# Convert cURL To Applescript

Tags: json, applescript, dropbox-api

I am trying to convert a cURL command to AppleScript Using "do shell script".
I've used various hints from previous posts but I'm still running into errors.
Can anyone point out errors in my syntax.

The below script works fine when run in terminal.

```
    curl -X POST https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer MYTOKEN' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' \
  --header 'Dropbox-API-Arg: {"path":"/RoomVT/Clown2.jpeg"}' 
  --data-binary @"/Splash.jpeg"
```

I then adapt as.

```
--Add do shell script Command--
--Place The cURL Inside Double Quotes--
--Replace Double Quotes With Single Quotes--
--Remove Backslashes At End Of Lines--
--You May Also Need To Place All In A Single Line--

do shell script "curl -X POST https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload --header 'Authorization: Bearer MYTOKEN' --header 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' --header 'Dropbox-API-Arg: {'path':'/RoomVT/Clown2.jpeg'}' --data-binary @'/Splash.jpeg'"
```

I still get the error.

"Error in call to API function \"files/upload\": HTTP header \"Dropbox-API-Arg\": could not decode input as JSON"

Comment: If you just take what's inside of `do shell script "..."` and paste `...` in **Terminal**, and execute it that way, does it work?

Comment: In `--header` argument, you have single quotes inside single quotes which isn't going to work. Maybe try adding a backslash before each of the 4 inner single quotes.

Comment: what happens if you break your shell script in two (between POST and the URL) with '& quoted form of '? Essentially leaving the 'curl -X POST' alone but using the 'quoted form' of the remainder of the line…. I get a 'no such file or directory' error 127, which you might not get.

Comment: In your `do shell script` change this part: `--header 'Dropbox-API-Arg: {'path':'/RoomVT/Clown2.jpeg'}'` to `--header 'Dropbox-API-Arg: {\"path\":\"/RoomVT/Clown2.jpeg\"}'` - note JSON must have double quotes (`"`) to be valid, and AppleScript requires each double quote to be escaped, i.e. `\"`. Likewise, you may need to change this part `--data-binary @'/Splash.jpeg'` to `--data-binary @\"/Splash.jpeg\"` - again note the escaped double quotes, i.e. `\"`, instead of single quotes (`'`).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your comments.
I went with @RobC suggestion and it worked first time.

```
do shell script "curl -X POST https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload --header 'Authorization: Bearer b4Itg9wetFIAAAAAAAAD7PPkCmoIE2oXvkx_-nq1L2D5G7Bfla-5LHKHtJqoeBMc' --header 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' --header 'Dropbox-API-Arg: {\"path\":\"/EngineRoomVT/Clown2.jpeg\"}' --data-binary @\"/Splash.jpeg\""
```